# $GL_2(\Bbb C)$ acts on a certain set

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, group-theory, group-actions

Let $G:=GL_2(\Bbb C)$, $B$ and $T$ be the subgroup consisting of all upper triangular 
and diagonal matrices in $G$, respectively. 
Set $w:= 
\left( \begin{array}{cc}
0 & 1\\
1 & 0
\end{array}\right)$ and
$w'= 
\left( \begin{array}{cc}
1 & 1\\
1 & 0
\end{array}\right)$.

I want to prove the following:

> $(1)$ $G=B\cup BwB, \quad B\cap BwB= \emptyset ,\quad
> BwB=TwB\cup Tw'B,\quad TwB\cap Tw'B=\emptyset$.

I can prove all but except the third, $BwB=TwB\cup Tw'B$.

> $(2)$ Suppose that $G$ acts on a set $M:=G/B\times G/B\times G/B$ as follows:
>   $$
> G\times M \ni (g,\gamma) \longmapsto g\cdot \gamma \in M,$$
>   where $g\cdot \gamma = ((gx)B,(gy)B,(gz)B),\gamma =(xB,yB,zB), (x,y,z\in G)$.
>   Determine $G$-orbit decomposition w.r.t the above action.

I cannot see why this is related to $(1)$.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The action of $G$ by multiplication on the the left cosets of $B$ is equivalent to the projective action of $G$ on the $1$-dimensional subspaces of ${\mathbb C}^2$, since $B$ is precisely the stabilizer of $\langle (1\ 0)^{\rm T} \rangle$.

Now $w$ maps $\langle (1\ 0)^{\rm T} \rangle$ to $\langle (0\ 1)^{\rm T} \rangle$, which is stabilized by $T$, so $TwB=wB$.

And $w_1$ maps $\langle (1\ 0)^{\rm T} \rangle$ to $\langle (1\ 1)^{\rm T} \rangle$, which can be mapped by elements of $T$ to any other $1$-dimensional subspace $\langle (a\ b)^{\rm T} \rangle$ of ${\mathbb C}^2$.

So we have the third equality $BwB = TwB \cup Tw_1B$.

Comment: What do you mean by writing $\langle (a\ b)^{\rm T} \rangle$ of ${\mathbb C}^2$?

Comment: By ${\mathbb C}^2$ I mean the $2$-dimensional column vectors over ${\mathbb C}$, since that is the space being acted on by ${\rm GL}(2,{\mathbb C})$. So $\langle (a\ b)^{\rm T} \rangle$ is the $1$-dimensional subspace of ${\mathbb C}^2$ spanned by the column vector $(a\ b)^{\mathrm T}$.

Comment: So $\langle (a\ b)^{\rm T} \rangle=\{c(a\ b)^{\rm T}: c \in \Bbb C\}$?

Comment: Yes that's right!

Comment: At your second line, I don't understand what you defined stabilizer of a $\textit{set}$ $\langle (1\ 0)^{\rm T} \rangle$. Also, I found $\{\left( \begin{array}{cc}1 & x\\0 &y\end{array}\right):y \ne 0\}$ is the stabilizer of $(1\ 0)^{\rm T}$.

Comment: As I said before, $W:= \langle (1\ 0)^{\rm T} \rangle$ is a $1$-dimensional subspace of ${\mathbb C}^2$, and $B$ is its stabilizer. That is, $W = \{g \in G : gW=W \}$. This action is very standard, and you need to be familiar with it to have any chance of understanding this material.

Comment: Thanks for the definition of stabilizer. Isn't more well-known by the name $\textit{strict stabilizer}$? Now I understand this part. Actually, I also have found other way to prove the third equality by considering typical elements of both sides. I am left with question $(2)$.